# Can I retrieve query execution time, other stats with AWS DynamoDB SDK for NodeJS?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm looking for a way to get statistics (such as execution time) of the query and then attach them to a JSON object along with the actual retrieved data so I can then send it to the client-side.

Sorry if this is a silly question but I tried searching the documentation and googled around but I guess it's either not possible or using the wrong keywords.

In case it's relevant, here's the code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-west-2'
});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();



let getLoginsByRole = function (a_role, a_site) {
    const params = {
        TableName: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        FilterExpression: '#Role= :Role AND #Site= :Site',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#Role': 'Role',
            '#Site': 'Site'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':Role': a_role,
            ':Site': a_site
        },
    };

    docClient.scan(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error when attempting table scan, see below:\n\n" + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            return err;
        } else {
            var matchingItems= [];
            data.Items.forEach(element => matchingItems.push(element.alias))

            var responseObject = JSON.parse('{"role":' + JSON.stringify(a_role) +
                ',"matchingItems":' + JSON.stringify(matchingItems) +
                ', "itemCount":' + data.Count + "}");
            console.log(responseObject);
            return responseObject;
        }
    })
}
getLoginsByRole("XXXXX", "XXX");
```

As you can see, there's a `responseObject` that looks like (added a comment next to the stats I'd like to see):

```
{
  role: 'Admin',
  matchingItems: [
    'billy',
    'jim',
    'pam',
    'ryan',
    'kerry',
    'karen'
  ],
  itemCount: 6,
  queryExecTime: 356ms, //I'd like something like this line...
  resultSetSize: 37kB   //And this line
}
```

Anyway thank you for your help, I'm learning DynamoDB and there's not much stuff out there and the SDK documentation is very obscure.